# Calculations on selected groups of variables

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with variable names looking like:

```
a.1, a.3,  a.5,  a.6,  a.9, a.10, a.12

b.1, b.3,  b.5,  b.6,  b.9, b.10, b.12
```

and so on from a to j.

The variables' names represent assessed parameters and visit number in a longitudinal study.

The dataframe also contains fixed baseline parameters.

I would like to create new variables which represent changes since the last visit for each parameter:

```
delta.a.3 <- a.3 - a.1
delta.a.5 <- a.5 - a.3
```

and so on for all visits for all parameters.

Is there any way to perform this task automatically?

Here is an extract from my dataframe:

```
      ID      DIAB    AGE 20MPACE.0 20MPACE.1 20MPACE.3 20MPACE.5 KOOSKPL.0 KOOSKPL.1 KOOSKPL.3 KOOSKPL.5
1 9000099       0     59    1.3280    1.2946    1.3500    1.2772    100.00     88.89     80.56     83.33
2 9000296       0     69    1.3658    1.3142        NA    1.3944    100.00    100.00    100.00    100.00
3 9000622       0     71    1.4305    1.5178        NA        NA    100.00    100.00        NA        NA
4 9000798       0     56    1.0636    1.2342    1.1969    1.1572     59.38     59.38     65.63     59.38
5 9001104       0     72    1.3924    1.3473        NA        NA    100.00    100.00     83.33        NA
6 9001400       0     75    1.6203    1.5015    1.5051    1.4264    100.00    100.00    100.00     91.67
```

ID, DIAB, AGE - "stationary" baseline parameters. 20MPACE.0, 20MPACE.1,  20MPACE.3,  20MPACE.5 - observations of 20MPACE on timepoints 0, 1, 3, 5. 
KOOSKPL.0, KOOSKPL.1 KOOSKPL.3, and  KOOSKPL.5 - observations of KOOSKPL on timepoints 0, 1, 3, 5.

What I would like to do:

1. To calculate changes in parameters on different timepoints in comparison with **previous timepoint**

   20MPACE.1-20MPACE.0

   20MPACE.3- 20MPACE.1

   20MPACE.5-20MPACE.3

   KOOSKPL.1 - KOOSKPL.0

   KOOSKPL.3 -  KOOSKPL.1

   KOOSKPL.5 - KOOSKPL.3
2. To place this results in corresponding columns:

   delta.20MPACE.1

   delta.20MPACE.3

   delta.20MPACE.5.

   delta.KOOSKPL.1

   delta.KOOSKPL.3

   delta.KOOSKPL.5
3. To calculate changes in parameters on different timepoints **in relation to timepoint 0**:

   20MPACE.1-20MPACE.0

   20MPACE.3- 20MPACE.0

   20MPACE.5-20MPACE.0

   KOOSKPL.1 - KOOSKPL.0

   KOOSKPL.3 -  KOOSKPL.0

   KOOSKPL.5 - KOOSKPL.0
4. Again, to place the results in columns:

   delta0.20MPACE.1

   delta0.20MPACE.3

   delta0.20MPACE.5.

   delta0.KOOSKPL.1

   delta0.KOOSKPL.3

   delta0.KOOSKPL.5

I did not ask the last two questions in first instance.

May be the point is to make loop work selectively on variables with the same prefix (e.g. 20MPACE.0, 20MPACE.1,  20MPACE.3 , 20MPACE.5)?  Is there a way to do it?

I very much appreciate prompt and informative comments you have made!
However, as a beginner I need some time to process the information and I still do not understand everything you told me.

Thanks again.

Comment: You need to edit this question. Show some sample data, posting the output of `dput(mydataframe)` or possibly `dput( head( mydataframe) )` if your data is large, and some notion of the expected output. Are we supposed to guess at the structure of your data. The question is not *clear* enough to answer satisfactorily as it stands. At a guess, I would say you are looking to `apply` something like `diff()` across the columns of your dataframe (or perhaps the rows).

Answer (score 2):

I see two possibilities in what you want, but you're really not clear in your question. Possibility #1 is as Maxim K has assumed, `diff` across each row for the full `data.frame`. Possibility #2 is that you want `diff` across each row *by group* ("a" to "j").

Before we start, here's some sample data. I've only done for groups "a" and "b".

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(matrix(sample(100, 50, replace = TRUE), ncol = 10))
names(mydf) <- paste(rep(c("a", "b"), each = 5), c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9), sep = ".")
mydf
#   a.1 a.3 a.5 a.7 a.9 b.1 b.3 b.5 b.7 b.9
# 1  27  90  21  50  94  39  49  67  83  79
# 2  38  95  18  72  22   2  60  80  65   3
# 3  58  67  69 100  66  39  50  11  79  48
# 4  91  63  39  39  13  87  19  73  56  74
# 5  21   7  77  78  27  35  83  42  53  70
```

#### Possibility #1

```
mydf[-1] - mydf[-length(mydf)]
#   a.3 a.5 a.7 a.9 b.1 b.3 b.5 b.7 b.9
# 1  63 -69  29  44 -55  10  18  16  -4
# 2  57 -77  54 -50 -20  58  20 -15 -62
# 3   9   2  31 -34 -27  11 -39  68 -31
# 4 -28 -24   0 -26  74 -68  54 -17  18
# 5 -14  70   1 -51   8  48 -41  11  17
```

#### Possibility #2

```
lapply(letters[1:2], 
       function(x) {
         temp <- mydf[grepl(paste("^", x, sep = ""), names(mydf))] 
         temp[-1] - temp[-length(temp)]
       })
# [[1]]
#   a.3 a.5 a.7 a.9
# 1  63 -69  29  44
# 2  57 -77  54 -50
# 3   9   2  31 -34
# 4 -28 -24   0 -26
# 5 -14  70   1 -51
# 
# [[2]]
#   b.3 b.5 b.7 b.9
# 1  10  18  16  -4
# 2  58  20 -15 -62
# 3  11 -39  68 -31
# 4 -68  54 -17  18
# 5  48 -41  11  17
```

Of course, this is just to get you started, because I'm not at all clear on your end goal here.

Comment: +1 Very illustrative and nice use of subsetting over `diff`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to automatically assign variable names throughout certain ranges. You will need to adjust the following code to your situation, as it was not specified exactly, as @SimonO101 noted. Suppose your original dataframe is called `df`:

```
delta <- matrix(NA,nrow=nrow(df))         # this will be the matrix of differences

for (i in 2:(ncol(df))) {
  delta <- cbind(delta,df[,i] - df[,i-1]) # in this loop we take the differences between 
}                                         # i'th and i-1'th element. You may want to adjust this.

result.df <- cbind(delta[,-1],df)         # combine both matrices (coerced to dataframe)

# finally, name the variables using paste()
names(result.df) <- c(paste0("diff",2:ncol(df),".",1:(ncol(df)-1)),names(df))
```

What happens in the last line is that we create a vector of variable names for new variables by `paste`-ing (combining) the following values: new variable name prefix (diff), the number of the first variable in the subtraction, dot, name of the second variable. The we c()ombine that the original name vector. You may want to run `paste0("diff",2:ncol(df),".",1:(ncol(df)-1))` separately to see how that works. Adjust the arguments of `paste0`to your needs. Hope this helps.

Comment: +1. FYI, You can subtract one `data.frame` from another provided they are the same dimensions. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16080002/1270695) for an example.

Comment: This would be better indeed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed my own data since you don't have the real values here.

```
## create two vectors of length 10
> hello <- seq(from=1, by=5, length =10)
> hello1 <- c(5,11,13,18,25,26,54,98,78,100)

> jd <- rbind(hello,hello1)
# Create a dataframe
> h1 <- data.frame(jd)
> h1
       X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
hello   1  6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41  46
hello1  5 11 13 18 25 26 54 98 78 100
> 
> jd1 <- apply(h1,1,diff)
> jd1
    hello hello1
X2      5      6
X3      5      2
X4      5      5
X5      5      7
X6      5      1
X7      5     28
X8      5     44
X9      5    -20
X10     5     22
```

In the data frame `jd1` , `x2` is the difference of `x2-x1` for `hello` and `hello 1` which is equivalent to `a.3 - a.1` that you are looking for.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much everybody! I am sorry that I did not formulate my question clearly.

Comment: Actually, I just have not yet found a good way to paste a part of my real dataframe into my question. Thanks again, I am trying to apply your suggestions.

Comment: Hi, you can use the command `dput(df)` where `df` is the name of your dataframe. You can update the output of your `dput` command in your question so that we can assist you better.